# Sending a file from one device to another. Both devices are connected to the same wi-fi network

Tags: javascript, jquery, bluetooth, connection, wifi

I am developing a web-based app whose goal is to share files among devices on the same wifi connection. I am a javascript developer but i have never worked with connections technology. Is there a way i can do this using javascript/jquery or any other API?

I am only aware of Network Information API which returns the information of connection type among other few information. So far, i can only check the connection type and speed.

```
var connection = navigator.connection || navigator.mozConnection || navigator.webkitConnection;
if (connection) {
    var connection_type=connection.type;
    var effectivetype=connection.effectiveType;
    var downSpeed = connection.downlink;
    console.log('download speed'+downSpeed +'effectivetype:'+effectivetype'+ 
    Connection type:'+connection_type);
}
```

```
var connection = navigator.connection || navigator.mozConnection || navigator.webkitConnection;
if (connection) {
    var connection_type=connection.type;
    if (connection_type=='wifi') {
    //the device is connected to a wifi
    var wifi_name = 'mywifi';
        if (wifi_name == 'mywifi') {
            //device is connected to my wifi
            var create_connection = create a connection();
            if (create_connection) {
                //a connection is created between two devices
                send_file();
                //send a file
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK browsers cannot create P2P (peer to peer, client to client) connection. They can only connect to HTTP or FTP server. To transfer a file, you would need to upload it to your server and then download it back. In theory you could pair the devices using their public IP if they are on same WiFi.

Answer (score -1):

I came across this webpage which offers something like what you need, check it out: www.bridgefy.me